# How to change class of an element from ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm getting info from a json file and creating a table with the results. what i need to do is to change the class of one of the elements on a click.

this is part of my code:

```
$scope.firstAvailables = function(){
    $http.get('/app/json/products.json')
    .then(function(data){
        $scope.listOfProducts = data.data.products;
    }
```

The html view:

```
<table class="table">
   <thead>
       <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Nickname</th>
          <th>Actions</th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
       <tr ng-repeat="x in listOfProducts">
          <th><a class="one">{{x.name}}</th>
          <th><input type="text" class="form" id="theBox" value="1" style="width:40%"></th>
          <th><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="toChange(x)">Change</button></th>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

What i want to do is to change the class from the input on different rows (not all, just a few). For that, i'm using the next piece of code that lives inside of `toChange(x)` (which lives on the button):

```
$scope.toChange = function(val){

//to get the specific value
var specific = val;

//to create a new name for the class
var y = 'some-' + specific.name;

//with JQuery remove the previous class and add the new one
$('#theBox').removeClass('algo').addClass(y);

//With this i receive on the console all the input html tag
console.log(document.getElementById('theBox'));
    }
```

To here everything it's ok if i click on one row. But, if then i click on another, the class from the selected row, sum the name previous name and the new instead of replace:

console log from very first clicked element

```
<input type="text" class="algo-non" id="theBox" value="1" style="width:40%">
```

console for the second element

```
<input type="text" class="algo-non algo-mollit" id="theBox" value="1" style="width:40%">
```

console for the next element

```
<input type="text" class="algo-non algo-mollit algo-liquit" id="theBox" value="1" style="width:40%">
```

What can i do to prevent the sum of the previous class names? The idea is to have on every click:

first click:

```
<input type="text" class="algo-non" id="theBox" value="1" style="width:40%">
```

second click:

```
<input type="text" class="algo-mollit" id="theBox" value="1" style="width:40%">
```

third click:

```
<input type="text" class="algo-liquit" id="theBox" value="1" style="width:40%">
```

I'm using AngularJs, Javascript and Jquery.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: don't repeat `id="theBox"`  while use `ng-repeat`.

Comment: This piece of code looks wrong at couple of places...
1. using id in ng-repeat, 2. using jquery to add/remove class, 3. using removeClass to remove the class "algo" not "algo-`item.name`"

Comment: Mixing jQuery and AngularJS like that is asking for trouble. Use the [`ng-class` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) to manipulate classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `$('#theBox')` is selecting all of the inputs.

1. First click: the class `algo-non` is added to **all** of the inputs.
2. Second click: the class `algo-mollit` is added to **all** of the inputs.
3. Third click: the class `algo-liquit` is added to **all** of the inputs.

Use `id="theBox-{{ $index + 1 }}"` or `id="theBox-{{ item.name }}"`, then select the inputs individually.

```
// Guaranteed to be unique
<input type="text" class="form" id="theBox-{{ $index + 1 }}" value="1" style="width:40%">

// Risk duplicates (if items have same name)
<input type="text" class="form" id="theBox-{{ x.name }}" value="1" style="width:40%">
```

Comment: So, the id will be `theBox-non1` where "non" is the name of the element, right? Then, just have to replace on the JQuery function `$(theBox-non1).removeClass('form').addClass(y);` where `y` is the received value (item.name)?

Comment: Yes, something like that. You probably could avoid adding the `1` and use `$('#theBox-' + item.name')`

Comment: After make the changes, now on the console i get a null response `Cannot read property 'className' of null`